# Leaflet toggle marker clustering

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html

I am using the [Leaflet markercluster plug in](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), and now want to add a button to turn the clustering on/off. For that I wanted to use the [leaflet button plug in](https://github.com/jerroydmoore/leaflet-button), because I am already using it in my code.

I tried around with this piece of code and customized the lines with "sidebar" in it.

```
var button = new L.Control.Button('Toggle me', {
toggleButton: 'active'
});
button.addTo(map);
button.on('click', function () {
if (button.isToggled()) {
    sidebar.hide();
} else {
    sidebar.show();
}
});
```

I also have an overlay where I want to implement those layers then.

How I cluster my markers:

```
var extern2 = L.markerClusterGroup();
extern2.addLayer(extern);
```

Comment: I rolled back latest edit, since it was posted as a new question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437459/leaflet-toggle-marker-clustering-with-overlay?noredirect=1#comment714028_437459

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two layers, where `extern` layer contains original markers and `extern2` contains clustered markers. What you have to do in toggle control is just to add one layer to the map and remove the other.

Assuming that initially plain markers (non clustered) are shown, code could look something like this:

```
var extern2 = L.markerClusterGroup();
extern2.addLayer(extern);

map.addLayer(extern);

var button = new L.Control.Button('Show clusters', {
  toggleButton: 'active'
});
button.addTo(map);

button.on('click', function () {
  var txt;
  var controlElement = button.getContainer();
  if (button.isToggled()) {
    txt = 'Show clusters';
    map.removeLayer(extern2);
    map.addLayer(extern);
    }
  else {
    txt = 'Show markers';
    map.removeLayer(extern);
    map.addLayer(extern2);
  }
  controlElement.innerHTML = txt;
});
```