# Leaflet toggle marker clustering with overlay

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html

I am using the Leaflet [markercluster plug in](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), and now want to add a button to turn the clustering on/off. For that I wanted to use the [leaflet button plug in](https://github.com/jerroydmoore/leaflet-button), because I am already using it in my code.

```
var map = L.map('map', {zoom: 6,center: L.latLng([52.3900214, 12.419982])}),

osmLayer = new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

map.addLayer(osmLayer);

var extern2 = L.markerClusterGroup();
extern2.addLayer(extern);
 


var baseLayers = [
{
    name: "Open Street Map",
    layer: osmLayer
},
{
    name: "Satellit",
    layer: L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}')
},
{
    name: "Open Railway Map",
    layer: L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.openrailwaymap.org/standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution:  'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://www.OpenRailwayMap.org">OpenRailwayMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)',
    })
},
];

var overLayers = [
{
    group: "Radsatzdrehmaschinen",
    collapsed: false,
    layers: [
            {
            active:true,
            name: "externe Maschinen",
            layer: extern2
            },
    ]
},
];
var panelLayers = new L.Control.PanelLayers(baseLayers,overLayers, {
compact: true,
//collapsed: true,
collapsibleGroups: true
});

map.addControl(panelLayers);


var panelElement = document.getElementById(extern2._leaflet_id);
panelElement.parentNode.parentNode.style = 'border-color: #508B1B';

//until here i made it that the clustered markers are displayed by default    

var button = new L.Control.Button('Toggle me', {
toggleButton: 'active'
});
button.addTo(map);
button.on('click', function () {
if (button.isToggled()) {                //this option activates the clustered markers

var extern2 = L.markerClusterGroup();
extern2.addLayer(extern);

var baseLayers = [
{
    name: "Open Street Map",
    layer: osmLayer
},
{
    name: "Satellit",
    layer: L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}')
},
{
    name: "Open Railway Map",
    layer: L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.openrailwaymap.org/standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution:  'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://www.OpenRailwayMap.org">OpenRailwayMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)',
    })
},
];

var overLayers = [
{
    group: "Radsatzdrehmaschinen",
    collapsed: false,
    layers: [
        
            {
            active:true,
            name: "externe Maschinen",
            layer: extern2
            },
    ]
},

];
var panelLayers = new L.Control.PanelLayers(baseLayers,overLayers, {
compact: true,
//collapsed: true,
collapsibleGroups: true
});

map.addControl(panelLayers);


var panelElement = document.getElementById(extern2._leaflet_id);
panelElement.parentNode.parentNode.style = 'border-color: #508B1B';


} else {                         //this option activates the unclustered markers
    

var baseLayers = [
{
    name: "Open Street Map",
    layer: osmLayer
},
{
    name: "Satellit",
    layer: L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}')
},
{
    name: "Open Railway Map",
    layer: L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.openrailwaymap.org/standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution:  'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://www.OpenRailwayMap.org">OpenRailwayMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)',
    })
},
];

var overLayers = [
{
    group: "Radsatzdrehmaschinen",
    collapsed: false,
    layers: [
        
            {
            active:true,
            name: "externe Maschinen",
            layer: extern
            },
    ]
},
];
var panelLayers = new L.Control.PanelLayers(baseLayers,overLayers, {
compact: true,
//collapsed: true,
collapsibleGroups: true
});

map.addControl(panelLayers);

var panelElement = document.getElementById(extern._leaflet_id);
panelElement.parentNode.parentNode.style = 'border-color: #508B1B';
}
});
```

When clicking the button the unclustured markers appear and another overlay appears, so I would need to remove the clustured markers and the old overlay, everytime I click the button.

I know this Code is terribly at efficiency, but I did my best at making it as short as possible.
If I would be able to not define the overlay everytime, it would help alot.

Comment: There is no code above to turn clustering on/off, so it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, because I want that part to be done by the button, lets say clustering is on by default and can be turned off / on with the button.

Comment: You have answer to that here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437387/leaflet-toggle-marker-clustering. Use that in your code and then ask further questions.

Comment: This part works if there are just simple markers on the map, but i do not know how to implemt it with my overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have ability to switch between clustered and non clustered markers and have also possibility of having layer in layers control to show or hide it, another group layer `overlayGroup` has to be introduced. This layer is then referenced in layers control, but button control then adds/removes layers `extern` (not clustered) and `extern2` to group layer `overlayGroup` instead of map.

Also button control for showing/hiding clusters is shown only when `overlayGroup` is shown on the map, using layer events `add` and `remove` to take care of that.

Whole code could then look something like this (`extern` layer is created from random points with `turf.randomPoint`):

```
var osmLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
  })
var map = L.map('map', {center: [-37.82, 175.24], zoom: 8, layers: [osmLayer]});

var points = turf.randomPoint(200, {bbox: [174, -39, 176, -36]});
var extern = L.geoJSON(points);     

var extern2 = L.markerClusterGroup();       
extern2.addLayer(extern);

var overlayGroup = L.layerGroup();
overlayGroup.addLayer(extern);

var baseLayers = [
  {
    name: "Open Street Map",
    layer: osmLayer
  },
  {
    name: "Satellit",
    layer: L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}')
  },
  {
    name: "Open Railway Map",
    layer: L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.openrailwaymap.org/standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution:  'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://www.OpenRailwayMap.org">OpenRailwayMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)',
    })
  },
];

var overLayers = [
  {
    group: "Radsatzdrehmaschinen",
    collapsed: false,
    layers: [{
      active:true,
      name: "externe Maschinen",
      layer: overlayGroup
    }]
  },
];

var button = new L.Control.Button('Show clusters', {
  toggleButton: 'active'
});
button.on('click', function () {
  var txt;
  var controlElement = button.getContainer();
  console.log(button.getContainer());
  if (button.isToggled()) {
    txt = 'Show clusters';
    overlayGroup.removeLayer(extern2);
    overlayGroup.addLayer(extern);
    }
  else {
    txt = 'Show markers';
    overlayGroup.removeLayer(extern);
    overlayGroup.addLayer(extern2);
  }
  controlElement.innerHTML = txt;
});    

overlayGroup.on('add', function(evt) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    button.addTo(map);
  }, 10);
});
overlayGroup.on('remove', function(evt) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    button.remove();
  }, 10);
});

var panelLayers = new L.Control.PanelLayers(baseLayers,overLayers, {
  compact: true,
  collapsibleGroups: true
});    
map.addControl(panelLayers);
```